# Can $(X, \left \| \cdot \right \|_{T})$ being a Banach space imply $T$ as a closed operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a
> linear operator. For each element $x \in X$, define a norm (more
> specifically, the **graph norm**) $\left \| \cdot \right \|_{T}$ on
> $X$ by : $$\left \| x \right \|_{T} = \left \| x \right \| + \left \|
>  Tx \right \|$$ for $x \in X$.

I managed to prove that if $T$ is a closed operator, then $(X, \left \| \cdot \right \|_{T})$ is a Banach space, using Cauchy sequences.

I was wondering if it's possible to prove the other way around, respectively if $(X, \left \| \cdot \right \|_{T})$ is a Banach space, then $T$ is a closed operator and if so, how I could achieve this.

Comment: According to the most precise definition of a function, there is no distinction between the graph and the function itself.  In other words, the function **is** its graph.  Thus, when someone says that an operator is closed, this is to be interpreted quite literally!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x_n \to x$ and $Tx_n \to y$. Then $x_n, Tx_n$ are Cauchy sequences in the $X$ and $Y$ norm resp., so $x_n$ is Cauchy in the $\|\cdot \|_T$ norm, so $x_n \to z$ in $\|\cdot\|_T$ norm. So then clearly $x_n \to z$ in the norm on $X$ also, so $z = x$, but also by the definition of the $T$ norm, $Tx_n \to Tz = Tx$ in the $Y$ norm, but $Tx_n \to y$ so $y = Tx$, which is precisely the definition of a closed operator.